# Clickable overlapping div(s) and focus

Tags: html, css, opacity, overlap

I have a set of multiple circles of different opacity, each circle should be clickable and when clicked, should come into focus and the clicked on will come in front of the others.

simple you will say...

My question is what to use CSS or Jquery and how to achieve it

Example:

[image]

```
.circles{}
.round{opacity: 0.4;;width:75px;height:75px;border-radius: 50%; position: relative;}
.circle1{background:#0f4977;top: 35px;left: 200px;z-index: 1;}
.circle2{background:#f41875;top: 0px;left: 250px;z-index: 2;}
.circle3{background:#6b259c;top: -50px;left: 205px;z-index: 3;}`


$(".round").click(function() {   //on click of any circle
    $(this).css("z-index", "99");
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");
    $(this).siblings().css("opacity", "0.5");
    $(this).siblings().css("z-index", "5");
});

<div clas="circles">
      <div class="round circle1"></div>
      <div class="round circle2"></div>
      <div class="round circle3"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cLqqfh4v/8/

Comment: What is your question and where is the code that you currently have? I am not sure if your question will be well received as SO is not a code writing service. Please provide your code and what you have tried and describe the problem you are having with your code

Comment: Doesn't this code work on your local? The fiddle is missing jquery but the code looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like...

```
$(".round").click(function() {   //on click of any circle
    $(this).css("z-index", "99"); //set this circle's z-index to 99, i.e. bringing it to the front
    $(this).css("opacity", "1");  //Set its opacity to 1 (opaque)
//Reset all other circles:
    $(this).siblings().css("opacity", "0.5");
    $(this).siblings().css("z-index", "5");
});
```

When your HTML is:

```
<div class="round" id="circle1></div>
<div class="round" id="circle2></div>
<div class="round" id="circle3></div>
```

Or something similar; your circles just have to have the class `circle`

See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jofish999/somad48j/1/

## Edit

---

As mentioned by **[@Sai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3392959/sai)**, a more efficient solution would be to have a CSS rule for the class `.opaque`. Then, instead of using jQuery to change the circle's CSS, you use `addClass()` to give it that class, then `removeClass()` to remove it again.

```
$(".round").click(function () { //on click of any circle
   $(this).addClass("opaque");
   $(this).siblings().removeClass("opaque");
```

Where your CSS is:

```
.opaque {opacity:1; z-index:99;}
```

Comment: Thanks Jofish, this what I had in mind, but doesn't work. See my upadted with JSFIddle

Comment: Got it. I'll have a look @wpsupprt

Comment: You just need to add jQuery down the left hand side. See my JSFiddle @wpsupprt

Comment: @Jofish  -- Good solution. Just a small improvement though. Instead of using css change in jquery ( which is not efficient) use add/remove class API to improve effieciency fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/svaidhyanath/somad48j/2/

Comment: Fair enough, I did think of that but didn't want to mess his/her code around too much. But good spot, I'll add that. @Sai